# How to include a html file into another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, apache

I am relatively new so I may not have done them right but I have tried them. The closest I got is the code I am including. It was work for awhile but the modals wouldn't "fire". I tried to remedy that and lost my inclusion. So here goes.

HTML

```
<!--============================================-->
<!--    End of Main Program, Modals Follow  -->
<!--============================================-->
<section id="activeModal">
     <!--> placeholder for every modal in this project </!-->
     <!--> each modal is stored in a separate file (modals.html) </!-->
     <!--> main.js builds an include with a js script, appends it here, and it executes (hopefully) </!-->
</section><!-- /activeModal -->
```

JS

```
// event listener for modals

$("button").on('click', function() {
    for ( i=0; i<this.attributes.length ;i++ ) {                     //  this - identifies the modal sought
        if ( this.attributes[i].name === "data-target" ) {
            var target = this.attributes[i].value;                  //  get the modal to "fire" (data-target attribute)
        };
    };
    modalId = "modals/"+target.substring(1, target.length)+".html";                        //  strip the '#' from target
    $("#activeModal").empty();                                                     //  remove any previous modal information
    includeHTML = '<!--#include virtual="'+modalId+'" -->';         //  include via ssi (server side include)
    $("#activeModal").append(includeHTML);                             //  append the 'import' html
    $(target).modal("show");                                                        //  show the modal
});
```

I am expecting the html for any of about 20 modals to appear in the activeModal `<section>` of `index.html`. Then, I have the problem of making them "fire".

Answer (score 1):

Based on this line, it looks like you are trying to use server-side includes on the client-side when a button is clicked.

```
includeHTML = '<!--#include virtual="'+modalId+'" -->';         //  include via ssi (server side include)
```

This is quite simply impossible.

You can't trigger a server-side include with client-side code. Server-side includes must be made before the response is sent to the client. To get more data from the server, you will have to initiate another request, perhaps via AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

```
var stackoverflowResponse = document.createElement("div");
stackoverflowResponse.innerHTML = "Look in the console for the answear";
document.body.replacewith(stackoverflowResponse);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the extension of your index.html to .shtml, and then using [Server Side Includes](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/webmaster/article.php/3473341/SSI-The-Include-Command.htm) to include the content of another file.

```
<!--#include file="included.html" -->
```

When I did this, I also believe I had to update the .htaccess file to recognize the .shtml as an index file:

```
AddType text/html .shtml
AddHandler server-parsed .shtml
AddHandler server-parsed .shtml .html
AddHandler server-parsed .shtml .htm
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try out something like this using jquery:

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#includedContent").load("xyz.html"); 
    });
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
     <div id="includedContent"></div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: I think I tried this in one of my flailing attempts. I'm going to try again though. Thanks.